# How can I change view UIScrollVIew by paging Mode?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, paging

I made a UIScrollView and add 2 SubViews.(View1, View2)

So, I can page down if i swipe because i set .isPagingEnabled = true.

And now I make a one button in View1.

What I want to do is change View2 when i click this button.

To be specific, change view by paging mode.(not like scrolling)

```
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(downBtnTapped), for: .touchUpInside)


 @objc func downBtnTapped() {
    if verticalScroll.contentOffset.y < self.view.bounds.height * CGFloat(2) {
        verticalScroll.contentOffset.y +=  self.view.bounds.height 
        }
    }
```

if i tried upper code, just chnage view directly, not like paging Mode

How can i solve this problem ?

Comment: add animation like this?  UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0) {
                self.verticalScroll.contentOffset.y +=  self.view.bounds.height
            }

Comment: @objc func downBtnTapped() {
        var contentOffset = verticalScroll.contentOffset
        contentOffset.y = self.view.bounds.height 
        verticalScroll.setContentOffset(contentOffset, animated: true)
    }